# JQuery/CSS - How i can set imagem full size of div

Tags: jquery, css

**html:**

```
<body>
    <div class="divD"><input type="button" id="x" name="button" value="Search"   onclick="showUser()" class="button"/></div>
    <input type="image" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Search" onclick="showUser()" class="button"/>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
#x
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-border-radius: 19px;
            -moz-border-radius: 19px;
            border-radius: 19px;
            background-color: #424242;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.75), inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,.75);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #454b54, #2b323b 50%, #363e46 51%, #6d7278);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #454b54, #2b323b 50%, #363e46 51%, #6d7278);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #454b54, #2b323b 50%, #363e46 51%, #6d7278);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #454b54, #2b323b 50%, #363e46 51%, #6d7278);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #454b54, #2b323b 50%, #363e46 51%, #6d7278);


        }

        .divD {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
        }
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
        var xxx ="img/on.png";
            $("#x").click(function(){
                $('#x').css({'background':' url('+xxx+') no-repeat','cursor':'pointer','border':' none'});
                alert("click");
                console.log("click");
            });
    });
```

i have input="button", and i will change my css of input="button" to add one image, but image not get full size of my div.

How i can set image full size of my div after i set event click (change image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqadh/)
[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqadh/1/)

```
background-size: cover;
```

or

```
background-size: 100% 100%;


$(function(){
        var xxx ="http://www.atecs.biz/img/nav_gradient.png";
            $("#x").click(function(){
                $('#x').css({'background':' url('+xxx+') no-repeat','cursor':'pointer','border':' none','background-size':'cover'});
            });
    });
```

Comment: Here, don't working, you only change "background-size: cover;" ?

Comment: Yeah, Demo 2 Working!
Thank you very much!! and god blessing you! :D

Comment: Worked in chrome and firefox ;D

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/HBs2d/1/)**</kbd>

Set the `background-size` of your element:

```
#x {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

And change the `background-image` only (not the whole `background` property) in your javascript:

```
$('#x').css({'background-image': 'url('+xxx+')'});
```

---

References:

- [Sizing Images: the ‘background-size’ property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) - W3C

Comment: Don't working =/, i need get image full set of div (the opposite occurred)

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of what happend to you?

Comment: The image need stay size of div, not the inverse

Comment: This will **scale** the image to fit in your div.

Comment: but i need have a input="button" in my <div>